# Success callback for Datatable server side processing ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to hide some columns after my server side call completes for the URL specified in

`sAjaxSource: url`,

and after I am done creating rows using `fnCreatedRow`. I Want to execute column visibility statements

`table.fnSetColumnVis(0, false, false);`

for multiple columns in this callback. Is there a way to do this in datatable? I have tried using `fnDrawCallback` and `fnRowCallback` but they do not execute at all.

The code I have written is as follows.

```
table = $('#ID').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "autowidth": true,
    //"bInfo": false,
    "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',

    "scrollY": "350px",
    "scrollCollapse": false,
    "paging": true,
    "scrollX": true,
    "destroy":true,
    "sAjaxSource": url,
    "aoColumns": [
     {
           "targets": 0,
           //"bVisible": true,
           "title": "Select Client",
           "bSearchable": false,
           "bSortable": false,
           "width": "10%"
       },//Many such entries
    ],
    "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aaData, iDataIndex) {
     //Function body
    },
    "drawCallBack" : //Actual code that i want to get executed after fnCreatedRow has ended
});
```

Comment: You want a callback after you get the data or after the table is drawn?

Comment: after the table is drawn

Comment: Have you tried without the `fn`? Just `drawCallback`? And where do you have this in your code? If it's not in the right place, it won't work.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
"drawCallback": function(settings) {
               //do whatever
            }
```

https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback

Comment: Be carefull, the link you provide apply to version 1.10 and over. But the parameter names in the question suggest nnm is using a legacy version of dataTables, anterior to 1.10.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar case, I solved it by attaching the xhr event to my datatable.

See: https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr

```
 $table.on('xhr.dt',
        function (e, settings, data, xhr) {
            //do something with the 'data' returned from server
            //OR handle some error using the 'xhr' request
        });
```

In my case $table is a var I declare upfront when initializing my datatable.